# Send message to friend on Facebook without native Android app

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I tried invite friends through [App Invites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android) but notifications only appear in the Facebook mobile app (not on the FB website).

So I tried use for this purposes [SendButton](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#buttons) but it works only when native FB app is installed.

How can I provide ability to send invites to my app for users? (without FB native app)